# How can I write a generic function that takes either an ndarray Array or ArrayView as input?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I am writing a set of mathematical functions using `ndarray` which I would like to perform on any type of `ArrayBase`. However, I'm having trouble specifying the traits/types involved.

This basic function works on either `OwnedRepr` or `ViewRepr` data:

```
use ndarray::{prelude::*, Data}; // 0.13.1

fn sum_owned(x: Array<f64, Ix1>) -> f64 {
    x.sum()
}

fn sum_view(x: ArrayView<f64, Ix1>) -> f64 {
    x.sum()
}

fn main() {
    let a = Array::from_shape_vec((4,), vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", sum_owned(a.clone()));

    let b = a.slice(s![..]);
    println!("{:?}", sum_view(b));

    // Complains that OwnedRepr is not ViewRepr
    //println!("{:?}", sum_view(a.clone()));
}
```

I can understand why the commented out section doesn't compile, but I don't understand generics well enough to write something more... generic.

Here is what I tried:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Data;

fn sum_general<S>(x: ArrayBase<S, Ix1>) -> f64
where
    S: Data,
{
    x.sum()
}
```

The compiler error suggests that `Data` is not specific enough, but I just can't parse it well enough to figure out what the solution should be:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:8:7
  |
6 |     S: Data,
  |             - help: consider further restricting the associated type: `, <S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem: std::clone::Clone`
7 | {
8 |     x.sum()
  |       ^^^ the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem: num_traits::identities::Zero` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:8:7
  |
6 |     S: Data,
  |             - help: consider further restricting the associated type: `, <S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem: num_traits::identities::Zero`
7 | {
8 |     x.sum()
  |       ^^^ the trait `num_traits::identities::Zero` is not implemented for `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
4 | fn sum_general<S>(x: ArrayBase<S, Ix1>) -> f64
  |                                            --- expected `f64` because of return type
...
8 |     x.sum()
  |     ^^^^^^^ expected `f64`, found associated type
  |
  = note:         expected type `f64`
          found associated type `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem`
  = note: consider constraining the associated type `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem` to `f64`
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

Comment: What happens when you follow the compiler's suggestions ("help: consider..." / "note: consider ...")?

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the tip. I did try adding Elem = A, but that seemed to open up a whole new can of worms (which might have been unrelated) so I decided to ask the more general question here. I see now that the most relevant section was "consider constraining the associated type `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem` to `f64`" but I just couldn't turn that into actual code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the [`ndarray::ArrayBase::sum`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.sum) function that you're attempting to invoke:

```rust
impl<A, S, D> ArrayBase<S, D>
where
    S: Data<Elem = A>,
    D: Dimension,
{
    pub fn sum(&self) -> A
    where
       A: Clone + Add<Output = A> + Zero
    {
         // etc.
    }
}
```

It's clear that in your case `A = f64` and `D = Ix1`, but you still need to specify the constraint `S: Data<Elem = f64>`.  Therefore:

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Data;

fn sum_general<S>(x: ArrayBase<S, Ix1>) -> f64
where
    S: Data<Elem = f64>,
{
    x.sum()
}
```

Which is exactly what the compiler meant when it suggested:

```
  = note:         expected type `f64`
          found associated type `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem`
  = note: consider constraining the associated type `<S as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem` to `f64`
```

Comment: Perfect! I did try Elem = A, but that only seemed to cause more problems so I backed away from that thinking I was missing something... I didn't think of simply filling in what the A is in my context.